# Travelling to Morocco using UNLP for Iraqi citizen

Tags: visas, tickets, morocco, iraqi-citizens

I have a United Nations Laissez-Passer. Can I use it to travel to Morocco?  My nationality is Iraqi.

Comment: Will you be travelling on duty? https://www.globalhighlights.com/morocco/visa

Answer (score 2):

Not unless you are travelling on official UN duty.

Assuming you are departing from Iraq and will have a return ticket, [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true), the system used by airlines, visa exemption applies for *”Passengers with a Laissez-Passer issued by the United Nations traveling on duty”*.

You can check this on the [IATA Travel Centre website](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/) by inputting full details of your itinerary and travel documents.

See also [Guide to the
Issuance of
United Nations Travel Documents](https://cibtvisas.com/forms?formname=portalforms/UNDP/Introduction%20-%20Guide-to-the-Issuance-of-UN-Travel-Documents.pdf) and this question [What is the use of a blue UN Laissez-Passer?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104647/what-is-the-use-of-a-blue-un-laissez-passer)